# How do I make Appstats work using Python 2.7 threadsafe and webapp2?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My app uses the threadsafe version of python 2.7 and I would like to use Appstats with it.

I currently let the runtime container instantiate my app using `webapp2.WSGIApplication()` and unfortunately none of my modules are picked up in Appstats.

However, if I follow these http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html instructions I should use `run_wsgi_app()` to invoke my application. From what I understand using `webapp2.WSGIApplication()` confers several performance/app caching benefits.

How can I use Appstats with `webapp2.WSGIApplication()` and keep the performance benefits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be another manifestation of [Appstats are only working for one WSGIApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738518/appstats-are-only-working-for-one-wsgiapplication) (for which I filed an internal bug already, but also showed a work-around).

Answer (score 7):

I found that if I enabled appstates in app.yaml along with create the appengine_config.py file it seems to me it works with anything I throw at it.

app.yaml

```
builtins:
  - admin_redirect: on
  - appstats: on
```

appengine_config.py:

```
def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
    from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording
    app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)
    return app
```