# Improving the performance of Google local development server

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, web-development-server

As of recent i switched to the Google development server for my local development on Windows.

This resulted in an average request time of 5 to 10s, whereas it used to be below 1 second. On second note, on a Linux device and remote this is also below 1 second.

How would one go about monitoring where the loss of performance is?
Are there common practices that should be taken in consideration?

Extra information about the setup:

- Windows 10
- PHP55
- Laravel 5.1
- Using Blob storage
- Using MySql
- Using Memcache
- Not using cUrl

I did notice a lot of the performance of my pc is lost due to the fast-cgi in my processes tab. Which results in the occasional crash of fast-cgi.

Comment: why do you care about performance in local environment?

Comment: Because currently i have to develop on a big project where i have to wait 10 seconds for each request/ajax to return.This makes the development process unnecessary slow.

Comment: My point is, localhost won't be a good indicator of actual performance in the server, better deploy the code to server and test it from there to see the performance. Local dev app server is compatible but won't be great

Comment: Like i said in my post, remote is no problem, it has perfect performance.
I'm not looking for remote performance increase. I'm looking for local performance increase. My development speed halved since i have to wait +/- 10 second to see my code in the browser which makes front-end frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

If you have used Appengine before, I assume you already know this, but I don't have enough reputation to comment and ask the question in your original post, so I will put this here as a "simple" answer.

As far as I know the most common way of profiling these kinds of performance issues on the development server is with Appstats. I recently used it to troubleshoot some pesky, slow NDB issues.

**Python**: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

**Java**: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats

It will let you trace down to individual RPC calls and whatnot to figure out why the response time is so long.

I hope that helps.

This will hopefully help guide you as well:

[How do I get appstats to work with webapp2 and extended routing on GAE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795066/how-do-i-get-appstats-to-work-with-webapp2-and-extended-routing-on-gae)

Comment: This gave me a little insight, but did not fix the problem.
I did manage to find that my performance is lost when accessing the bucket. any thoughts ?

Comment: So if you remove all references to your local GCS bucket for a given request, it returns to normal speed? Unfortunately I haven't experienced nor  seen anything similar to this kind of problem before. Sorry I couldn't be of more direct assistance.